# DNN with tflearn always predicts the same value

Tags: python, deep-learning, tflearn

I am just starting with using tflearn/tensorflow for machine learning, and I am having a problem with the model below. 
It always predicts the same outcome, out of two possible from the data set (0 or 1).
I have made sure that my inputs are of fdatatype float, and that my training set is balanced. Any idea what could be causing the issue?
Here is the code:

```
def build_model():
    tf.reset_default_graph()

    net = tflearn.input_data([None,11])
    #Hidden layer
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net,1,activation='softmax')
    net = tflearn.regression(net,optimizer='sgd',
                              learning_rate=0.1,
                             loss="categorical_crossentropy")
    model = tflearn.DNN(net)
    return model

model = build_model()

model.fit(np.asarray(Xtrain),np.asarray(Ytrain),validation_set=0.1,show_metric=True,n_epoch=30,batch_size=50)
```

Thanks!